# Bootstrap 4 Webpack Sass functions not working

Tags: webpack, sass, bootstrap-4, node-sass

Having an issue with Webpack and Bootstrap 4 mixins and functions.

sass|css loader:

```
{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
        // fallback to style-loader in development
        // which creates style nodes from JS strings (IE: imports)
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                includePaths: ['node_modules']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

imported with:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/print";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

Everything seems to work great, except when it comes to the mixins and functions.

For example, `color: color("purple");` works just fine, and places the proper color, however a simple `<span className="badge badge-green ml-2">badge here</span>` loads the base styles for the badge, but not the color variant for green.

There are no errors of any kind, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the color variant "green" in the `$theme-colors` bootstrap variable?

By default there are the following options only (copied from `bootstrap/_variables.scss`):

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "secondary":  $secondary,
    "success":    $success,
    "info":       $info,
    "warning":    $warning,
    "danger":     $danger,
    "light":      $light,
    "dark":       $dark
  ),
  $theme-colors
);
```

The `$theme-color` variable is used by all the components for the color modifiers like this (copied from `bootstrap/_badge.scss` using the badge component as an example):

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .badge-#{$color} {
    @include badge-variant($value);
  }
}
```

So if you want to use a color variant "green" you have to register it in the `$theme-colors` variable first like this (wherever you override your default bootstrap variables):

```
$theme-colors: (
  "green": #00ff00
);
```

More info can be found at the documentation for the badge component (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/) and the documentation for theme colors (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#theme-colors) by bootstrap itself.

Comment: yep, that was it! I didn't dig deep enough into the docs! Thanks!